# Is it recommended to have one subscription for every application in your organisation?

Tags: azure, subscription

For a large corporate, we have designed an Azure subscription hierarchy:
Subscriptions for Prod and Non-Prod, each with:
- 1 VNET per subscription.
- Resource groups (RG) for Tiers (Web, App, DB)
- RG's have their own Subnets and NSG's.

The problem is, there are many applications. That means for example, all Production Database servers (for different applications) reside in the same Subnet in the same RG (and by default can talk to each other).

To prevent unrelated apps from talking, it has been suggested to create 1 subscription per application. That would result in increased complexity and duplication of resources, due to having 1000's of subscriptions, and VNETs and IP ranges. Is this recommended? Are there better ways to manage that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you should think of design your Azure scaffold is as below:

1. Number of subscriptions should always be a function of the number of independent solutions and environments (read as standard dev, test, and prod) expected in the application lifecycle
2. All related data and hence their respective applications should ideally reside in one subscription and hence you should think in terms of multiple resource groups
3. Hosting solutions in a VNET is a choice to implement the design by security and always compliments when you end up solutions which may lead to joining colo DC's with Azure either using VPN (S2S or P2S) or even Azure ExpressRoute
4. In your case where you mention more than 1000 applications, given the above ideas in mind, you should start rationalizing how you want to allocate subscriptions and hence respective resource groups. Note that here's where `Azure Management Groups` proves very useful to oversee and administer such complex solutions.
5. Building logic for NSG and WAF's to control ingress/egress should be enforced to control traffic and application exploitation

Great if you can now improve your question (or add follow-ups) and ask specific details to proceed to next stage.

Comment: The main goal is to control (restrict) traffic flow between different groups of servers. Traditional way is to create different subnets, and to use a firewall to control traffic based on port, direction and IP ranges (subnets).But at the same time, I want to limit the number of subnets created. Do not want to manage a firewall rulebase with 1000's of rules for 1000's of different subnets.

Comment: So one way is to create management groups for Dev, Test and Prod. In each of these, we have subscriptions.
The subscriptions have VNETs which are peered, so we can control flow of traffic between Dev and Prod subscriptions for example.Then inside each subscription, e.g. inside the prod subscription, we could create different resource groups, each with its own subnet and NSG. These are for Web, App and DB tiers. That way, we could control traffic flow between e.g. App and DB Tiers.

Comment: We still have multiple different applications. And we want to restrict traffic between different applications.
So we could, for example, create multiple Production Subscriptions (one for each app), and similarly multiple Dev and multiple test subscriptions. That results in a lot of subscriptions. As an alternative to the above, we could have all Production applications in the same subscription, in the respective tiers (and same for dev and test subscriptions). The we have for example all the DB servers of all the applications in the same RG, in the same subscription (on the same subnet).

Comment: So how do you restrict network traffic between them? In other words, how else could you control access between different groups of servers? e.g. via Tagging or via Application Security Groups?

Comment: If these applications are hosted as containerized apps then labeling (read as selectors) are very useful and Network Policies can be created to control ingress/egress.

Comment: If these applications are not hosted as containerized apps then ASG's and NSG's should be deployed to control ingress/egress of traffic. But more important cases here is to rationalize your scaffold if there is an opportunity.